# App ignores Persian locale

Tags: android, persian, android-8.0-oreo

On Android 8.0 changing device language to Persian sets app UI to LTR. On versions below 8.0 everything is fine, setting any other (LTR or RTL) language on 8.0 also works.

In Settings I have 3 languages added: Persian, English, Russian.

`Locale.getDefault()` returns `en_US`.

`LocaleList.getAdjustedDefault();` returns {`en_US`, `fa_IR` `ru_RU`}.

Adding strings for Persian didn't change anything.

When I create a new empty project (no Persian strings, supports RTL) and run on the same device, everything works perfectly: UI is RTL, default locale is `fa_IR`.

There are no explicit locale changes in the app itself. 
What may affect app in this way?

PS: posting the whole project isn't possible.